# How to track the number of processes a call spawns

Tags: python, unit-testing, multiprocessing

I am writing a unit test of a function which is supposed to parallelize when possible within a given budget of processes. Without access to the function's internals, since I am outside it in my test code, how can I tell how many processes it is taking?

There may not be a way.

Comment: what is the name of the framework?

Comment: I recommend to read the code responsible for spawning to undersand how it works. Otherwise, in tree mode in top command will allow you to know the number of process that are ru by the tests

Comment: I'm just using standard unittest.

I wrote the code responsible for spawning the threads. I know how it works. That's not the issue. The issue is I want a test to sanity check myself for all time.

Comment: You what to spawn processus, not threads. Unittesting is CPU bound.